# Rails nested routes for simple blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I need to make page for my blog and also for each post under blog. It should look like this `example.com/blog/my_first_post`. Posts are static HTML files and I don't use any database.

Here is my routes:

```
  get 'blog' => 'static_pages#blog' do
    get '/my_first_post' => 'blog#my_first_post' 
  end
```

Here is my StaticPages controller:

```
  ...

  def blog
    def my_first_post
    end
  end

  ...
```

Blog page is working fine, but post is not working.

Comment: What exactly do you want ? do u have `posts` table ?

Comment: Please explain more your question, what post are you talking about? Is it post request or your literal post module?

Comment: just a static html under /blog page. no database! @7urkm3n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this `example.com/blog/my_first_post`, your routes should look like the followings -

```
get 'blog' => 'static_pages#blog'
get 'blog/my_first_post' => 'static_pages#my_first_post'
```

Your controller should be looking like this-

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def my_first_post
  end

  def blog
  end
end
```

Comment: @DanielsV check the updated answer. routes will hit `BlogsController`  `my_first_post` action. Put your logic inside `my_first_post` method.

Comment: there is no such thing as blog controller. Everything is under "static_pages controller" @dkp

Comment: @DanielsV OK, check the updated answer now. I have updated the routes and controller. Make sure you have kept `my_first_post` action inside `StaticPagesController`

Answer (score 0):

Check this one: but one thing

If its just static page then better use as like in below.

```
get 'blog/my_first_post' => 'static_pages#my_first_post'
```

you cannot call that method like view if its in it. make it like this.

```
  def blog
  end

  def my_first_post
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below, above resources: blog if present

```
get 'blog/my_first_post'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try:

```
get 'blog/my_first_post', to: Proc.new { |env|
    [
      200,
      {"Content-Type" => "text/html"},
      [File.read("public/my_first_post.html")] // where you static files are
    ]
  }
```

In your case, a controller is redundant